# Iterator malfunction when looping through string

Tags: string, loops, c++11, iterator, char

What I'm trying to do is get the user to input a phone number in a format they prefer and then remove the helper characters the user has used in their input using a loop which compares each character in the string with a another set of defined helper characters, if there is a match it erases that character from the string. I'm doing this as a practice problem to develop my understaing of iterators. I have successfully done this with the trivial for loop. However when I try to do it this way to my surprise whenever there are two helper characters like the "(+" the loop does not run for the next character which in this case is the "+". It direclt skips to the "9" and works fine after that. It does the same behaviour if other helper characters are present later on in the string. I have checked this by placing a cout << *i just under the first for loop. I don't understand why this would happen? Because of this the program fails to do what it's supposed to and out puts "+91892333" instead of the desired "91892333".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 string main = "(+91)892-333";
 string dictionary = "(+)-";

 for( string::iterator i = main.begin(); i !=  main.end(); i++)
 {


     for( char word : dictionary)
     {

                if(*i == word)
                {
                    main.erase(i);
                    break;
                }
     }
 }

 cout << main;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) `erase` invalidates iterators. So after you call `erase` you must not use iterators obtained before or you get UB. In your case `erase` does not change iterator but moves the end if the string after erased symbol one symbol left. So your iterator now points to the next character. But that behaviour is not guaranteed, std::string may allocate new buffer and move the data there, leaving old iterators pointing to nowhere.

Comment: got it adding a i-- after the erase function works like a charm, But shouldn't the iterator be invalidated?

Comment: When you write on C++ it is very common to use boost. It is sort of playground for STL. There is boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp where you can find functions which do exactly what you want. Or you can use std::remove_if and then drop unused end of the string with substr.